# Can I pass DATEADD straight into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

In one of the tSQLt tests I am writing I call a method with parameters to fill the expected table like so:

```
EXEC Test.Insert_Expected
    @CommencementDt = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE)
```

However I am getting an error over the MONTH part of the second line reading:

> 'Incorrect syntax near MONTH, expecting ( or SELECT'

I'm new to using parameterised methods and was wandering why this wasn't working, and how I might solve it? Thanks

Comment: Try `EXEC Test.Insert_Expected DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())`

Comment: You can pass *literal values* or *variables* in a call to `EXEC`. You *cannot* pass *arbitrary expressions*.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12236a2c-418d-46f6-ae2b-2a644e892f94/using-expression-for-a-stored-procedure-argument-syntax-error?forum=transactsql

Comment: Of course, even if you could, `getdate` is an invalid expression, too, so that's another problem you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead

```
DECLARE @CommencementDt datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
EXEC Test.Insert_Expected @CommencementDt
```

because you can't directly pass the result of a function into the input of a stored procedure. instead, you have to assign the result of the function to a variable and pass that variable to the sp

Comment: Ideally you'd also explain why this solves the problem. :)

Comment: @underscore_d added more detail

Answer (score -3):

Try using `GETDATE()` instead of `GETDATE`

Comment: Unless you are certain that your answer is correct, it would always be a good idea to test it yourself first before providing it as an answer